# How to delete specific rows with while?

Tags: r, while-loop, delete-row

I'm a beginner in R and I need some help:

In my database, very big since I'm working with micro-data, I want to remove some rows when there is a specific value of a Column...i was trying to implement some function to do that....but I'm having a problem with the IF condition(true/false problem). For example, I want to remove the row i when the column DISC in that line is "L", then i did this function:

```
dellinhas<-function(x){

  n<-nrow(x)
  i<-1
  while (i<=n) {
  if (x[i,]$DISC=="L") {x<-x[-(i:i),]}
  i<-i+1}
  dadosPrmM<-x
}
```

Where `x` is the database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use subscripting:

```
x[x$DISC != "L",]
```

And try this website for basic data manipulation issues: http://www.statmethods.net/

Comment: I second this. In R, you rarely find yourself using loops, generally you are either mapping over lists or using the (quite powerful) subscript notation.

Comment: Dear Vicent, now i have a problem related to the size the condicion asks and with that i have just one.do you have another idea???thanks man!!!

Comment: Vicent....i got it....thanks for the web site, i used ifelse: dellinhas2<-function(x){
 
 n<-nrow(x)
 i<-1
 while (i<=n) {
 ifelse(x[i,]$a==30,x<-x[-(i:i),],x<-x)
i<-i+1}
 }

Comment: Glad this helped. Feel free to accept my answer (click on the check sign) if you think it meets your needs.

Comment: The way Vincent showed you is also much faster, which becomes evident in "big data".